# Object definition SyntaxError

Tags: javascript

Why does the second line of code produce an error but not the third?

```
{ foo: 'bar' } // => 'bar'

{ "foo": 'bar' } // => SyntaxError: Invalid label

({ "foo": 'bar' }) // => { foo: 'bar' }.
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Try to find another way to phrase it.

Comment: Yeah. all three are valid JavaScript syntax. what are you really asking?

Comment: @mattsnider: Run the code in a JS console.

Comment: @Blender thank you edit. take a look at the question..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant part of the language specification is http://es5.github.com/#x12.4

> ExpressionStatement : [lookahead ∉ {`{`, `function`}] Expression `;`

The lookahead part means that something is only treated as an expression when it appears where a statement is expected if it does not start with `{` or `function`.

---

```
{ foo: 'bar' }
```

is a block of statements containing the expression statement `'bar'` with label `foo`.  Labels allow you to `break` or `continue` from named loops but can be attached to any statement, not just loops.

```
{ "foo": 'bar' }
```

The parser starts parsing this, finds an expression `"foo"` and then looks for a binary operator but `:` is not a valid binary operator so it fails with a syntax exception.

```
({ "foo": 'bar' })
```

Here the parentheses enter an expression context, so the `{` is treated as starting an object constructor instead of as the start of a block.